# OnTouch to other views than the first one touched on Android

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

In this case i am trying to make so my sidemenu that is made of textviews interactable.
There is no problem at all to do something simple like onClick. But i want the user to be able to drag from example: 1 to 9. Then the application will notice what it dragged over and where it stopped.

The big problem i have is that when i start touching one of the numbers and keep my finger on the screen. The touchevent will only react to the first number i touched. No matter where i drag my finger. So this is a big problem for me. I have tried adding a onHoverListener. But that one does not react at all

> > protected void setupFastScrollList()   {
> >         LinearLayout linearLayout;
> >         linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.history_side_index);
>
> ```
> TextView textView;
> int j = 6;
> for(int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
> {
>   textView = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tracker_history_sidemenu_item,null);
>
>   /* Add 0 infront or not */
>   String t  = String.valueOf(j);
>   if(t.length() == 1)
>   {
>     t = "0"+t;
>   }
>
>   textView.setText(String.valueOf(t));
>   linearLayout.addView(textView);
>
>   j++;
>   if(j == 24)
>   {
>     j = 0;
>   }
>
>   textView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
>   {
>     @Override
>     public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event)
>     {
>       TextView txt = (TextView) view;
>       Log.d("LOCATION","OnTouch: " + txt.getText());
>       return false;
>     }
>   });
>
>   textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
>   {
>     @Override
>     public void onClick(View view)
>     {
>       TextView txt = (TextView) view;
>       Log.d("LOCATION","OnClick: " + txt.getText());
>     }
>   });
>
>
> }   }
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write a custom ViewGroup and override onInterceptTouchEvent.

```
class MyViewGroup extends LinearLayout {
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(TouchEvent event) {
        // Check if the drag is done and return true to steal the touchevents away from the textviews.
    }

    public boolean onTouch(TouchEvent event) {
        // You will end up here after you return true from onInterceptTouchEvent
    }
}
```